# To understand elliptic partial differential equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am a graduate university student of mathematics. I would like to study elliptic partial differential equations on my own. I have tried [this](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr10.pdf) lecture note though I cannot understand it all as I never studied the following concepts:

- compact support
- the usual topology of Schwartz
- the space of distributions over Ω
- the space of all square integrable functions on Ω
- derivatives in sense of distributions

I definitely need to study some fundamentals before starting the lecture note. Can you tell me some fundamental materials I should read to understand the lecture note? Thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all explained in Rudin *Functional Analysis* up to ch. 6.  You might want to start with the Evans book on PDEs instead of with Lions' notes; the book demands fewer prerequisites, although you do need to know what compact support is (essentially that the function is zero outside a compact set) and what it means for a function $f$ to be square integrable on an open set $\Omega$ (essentially $\int_\Omega |f|^2 < \infty$).